# Facebook Like box won't work

Tags: javascript, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

My like box  doesn't work. When the like button is clicked it turns gray and says you've liked it, but when you refresh the page the box displays as if it isn't liked.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test FB like button</title>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="100003952948052" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nb_NO/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=163145893868097";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<fb:like href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the normal behavior, you have to wait.

What is `<fb:like` ? 
Normally you juste have to pu that :

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Comment: hm.. steel dosent work. But if i logout then like it i need to login and then it works... wierd!